# Paypal "Buy Now" button: success page parameters

Tags: java, paypal

I am implementing Paypal's "Buy Now" buttons in Java web application. What I couldn't find is adding Post parameters to Success Page URL after successful payment. Is it even possible?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean adding your own parameters, you can define them as request parameters in the return_url.

Comment: Thanks for the response EJP and sorry for the delay. Yes, what I need is to add my own POST parameters to the return URL. But where I can do it? I'm on sandbox.